# Function giving error when run on the same dataframe more than once

Tags: pandas

Function giving error when run on the same data frame more than once. it works fine the first time but when run again on the same df it gives me this error:

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

```py
def update_data(df):                                                             
    df.drop(df.columns[[-1, -2, -3]], axis=1, inplace=True)                      
    df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()                                                   
    df.iloc[-1, 0] = 'Group'                                                     
    df = df.set_index(list(df)[0])                                               
    for i in range(1, 21):                                                       
        df.iloc[-1, i] = 100 + (100 * (                                          
                (df.iloc[-1, i] - df.iloc[-1, 0]) / abs(df.iloc[-1, 0])))        
    df.iloc[-1, 0] = 100                                                         
    xax = list(df.columns.values)                                                
    yax = df.values[-1].tolist()                                                 
    d = {'period': xax, 'level': yax}                                            
    index_level = pd.DataFrame(d)                                                
    index_level['level'] = index_level['level'].round(3)                         
    return index_level
```

Comment: Please share a sample data and the expected output if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using `inplace=True` in a function changes the input data frame. Of course there it doesn't work, your function presumes the data is in some format at the start of the function. That assumption is broken.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'x': 0}])
def change(df):
    df.drop(columns=['x'], inplace=True)
    return len(df)

change(df)
Out[346]: 1

df
Out[347]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0]
```